# Multiple hosts on one site using Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Im using sonata cms and symfony 2, I have multisite set up which works fine, however I have a dev environment for local development and a 'demo' environment where the client can see where the deployed progress.

Im using the same database (for now) for both dev and demo, and the domains to both are completely different (eg. dev = dev-domain.com, demo = demo-domain.com)

When setting a site up in sonata you can enter the host you want the site to appear on, so for dev this is set to dev-domain.com, however on the demo site it doesn't work unless I change the host to be demo-domain.com.

My question is, is it possible to create multiple hosts for the one site, so I can add dev-domain.com and demo-domain.com and not have to change them around?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

- Upload your dev project on github
- Create your demo host on your server
- Pull the github repo from there
- Fill in your parameters.yml with the same database as in the dev instance

Everytime you want to update the demo with the new dev features just push from dev and pull from demo

Hope that helps

Comment: They do have the same parameters.yml thats the issue, sonata only allows one host for a site so if I set the site to have a host of example.dev then i visit from demo-example.com it wont work unless I update the database entry and change the site host to demo-example.com at which point it wont work locally anymore. its multiple hosts for a single site in sonata i need

Comment: What i was suggesting was having two instances.Both using the same code and the same database but each of them being under a different virtual host.So you end up with two separate sonata/symfony applications but being clones of eachother using a common database

Comment: If say same database is the issue as you assign a domain name to a site. There is such thing a multi host in sonata but can't really understand how to make it show the same site